# Is it possible to initiate a SF action from a third party application?

Tags: trigger, api

Is it possible to trigger a previously defined salesforce action (for example Post) from a third party application outside of salesforce? I looked at the REST API and other interface documentation and could not find an example. If there is already a document which discusses this process, please provide the link or point me to the right place.

To make this question more specific, here is the use case requested:
The user is in another application that tracks financials for a specific account. That account is lagging behind expected results. The finance person wants to add an action to the sales account owner / manager to make a call to this account. Rather than exiting the finance application and going to the Salesforce application to create the action item, we would like to initiate the action from the finance tool for an action to be created and tracked to completion in Salesforce. So, the action is already defined in SF. The finance app user would click a button in their current app. Enter the account information and the requested action information. That app would then handshake with SF and request the action be created using the information provided.   Is that possible, and if so, what would be the process to create. (Is there already a knowledge base article or similar help that documents the general way to do this?)

Thanks!

Comment: What kind of action? At our shop we have implemented a process in .NET to read a table, change the output to JSON and then send this JSON via a RESt Service to salesforce for some processing.

Comment: can you elaborate your usecase a little bit? what are you referring an action from third party?

Answer (score 2):

simplest way to do it just create a process using process builder and you can invoke those process via external system.

Yes you can use Postman to test your Services both rest or SOAP.
1 st you need to connected app
you will get consumer key and consumer secret that you will use to authenticate.

send post to
http://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token 
in body of payload add

Key value payer
client id your consumer key
client secret 
username 
password

you will get instance url
accesstoken token

by useing these instance url and token perform further request

Comment: it might be helpful if you pointed to the doc explaining how a Process Flow can be invoked from a REST or SOAP call

Comment: Yes, if there is a document that show steps or code snippets showing how to create the REST API call(s) to initiate a POST from a third part application please point me to that link! I Found the URL to that says it is possible: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/resources_list.htm but a step by step or example  how-to document would be greatly appreciated.